# Azure Services - Data Security

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

May I ask what is the security protocol (Https/TCPIP etc) applied in the following scenarios in Azure? I need these details to write my design document.

1. Between Azure Services

   - Azure Data Factory interacting with Azure Storage
   - Azure Databricks interacting with Azure Storage
2. Azure Python SDK connecting to Storage Account (Is it TCP/IP ?)

If there is any support page in MS Azure, please direct me there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Inside the Azure data centers used TLS/SSL for communication between
   services and you can read about it "Encryption of data in transit"
   section on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/encryption-overview).
2. The main SDK implementations are wrappers around the REST API and
   [Python SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/) is one of them.